# Rails assets app/assets and vendor/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-assets

I have read following in an article

> All of your custom Javascript, stylesheets, and images should go in
> the app/assets/.
>
> All third-party code that you are using (e.g. jQuery,
> backbone.js, etc.) should be placed in the vendor/assets/ directory

But I did not find in the article - Why it is recommended so, any reasons?

Comment: Have you tried to read [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction that you cant put third party `jQuery/CSS` in the `app/assets` folder.

But its recommended to put the third party assets in the vendor file. It will be easily manageable for the large applications and will save a lots of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Well I presume you are clear with `app/assets/` folder.

In vendor/assets you put all third-party code that you are using. 
So after you put that code in assets you need to require them in `application.css` and `application.js`.

This is doing on this way because rails by default look in `vendor/assets/` and it is easier to manage third-party code.